# Different ways of using assert in Groovy

Tags: groovy, junit, assert

I would like to know the difference between the usage of "assert" in the below two scenarios in groovy and also please explain when to use them as well.

```
  1) assert "done" == "done" ;true
```

and

```
  2) assert postDataToUrl[0].statusCode == 201
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what context?  Why have you put `true` on the end of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You use `assert` to enforce some conditions in your code.

For example if a variable *con* **must** de defined - i.e. must be not NULL you may place an assert such as:

```
 assert con != null
```

This leads to a general exception and termination of the execution if the variable is `con = null`.

You may add an explanation text, that is shown in the exception:

```
 assert con != null,"DB connection can't be established"
```

Some people are scared that in a productive code *unnecessary* assertions are checked and deactivate them. Other are scared that illegal consitions may occur in the productive execution and let them on.

Sorry I can't comment you `;true` option, but I thing you mean the two possibilities I explained.